# What is faster, `if x` or `if x != 0`?

Tags: python

I was wondering, what code runs faster? For example, we have variable x:

```
if x!=0 : return
```

or

```
if x: return
```

I tried to check with timeit, and here are results:

```
 >>> def a():
...     if 0 == 0: return
...
>>> def b():
...     if 0: return
...>>> timeit(a)
0.18059834650234943
>>> timeit(b)
0.13115053638194007
>>>
```

I can't quite understand it.

Comment: Unless you define the type of variable `x`, there exists no answer for this question.

Comment: `b` is faster because `0` is falsey, whereas all other numbers are truthy so you are performing only one operation not two.

Comment: @EliSadoff ...I could certainly write a class for which `a` were faster. Which is to say that you're making an assumption. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes but for a primitive type, such as integer, `b` is faster.

Comment: Sure, but the OP didn't specify that.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. Type of variable is indeed an integer.

Comment: a() is making a check on the value, b() is only testing existence of value. it is difficult to see in code in python since it is higher level, but in a lower level language it would be clearer, the test is almost immediate for b() when looking at registers since the values that give it are stored similarly register wise whereas a() is checking against specific value which will require a few more loops through the cpu arquictecture of registers

Comment: They are also not the same depending on what x could be.

Comment: Is '0' considered both integer and boolean False?

Comment: BTW, to be clear -- we get a *lot* of microoptimization questions in the Python tag, but as a rule, they and their answers are useless: The differences are both tiny *and implementation-defined*, so they aren't guaranteed to exist on a different version of the interpreter, a different target architecture, etc etc. If you care about shaving off nanoseconds, you're using the wrong language. The place to pay attention is on using efficient algorithms -- one algorithm-level tweak will generally overwhelm any performance you might have gained by trying to microoptimize.

Comment: ...which is to say: Build your algorithms for machines to efficiently execute, but write your code for humans to read.

Comment: they are **effectively equivalent** (with some exception... by the time you encounter or create exceptions you will know how to query them correctly) ... that is really all there is to say (note that in **some** cases the result is also equivalent like in the example where you are using an int,**this is not always the case**)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is too hard to show in a comment:  there's more (or less ;-) ) going on here than any of the comments so far noted.  With `a()` and `b()` defined as you showed, let's go on:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(b)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

What happens is that when the CPython compiler sees `if 0:` or `if 1:`, it evaluates them *at compile time*, and doesn't generate any code to do the testing at run time.  So the code for `b()` just loads `None` and returns it.

But the code generated for `a()` is much more involved:

```
>>> dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

Nothing is evaluated at compile time in this case - it's all done at run time.  That's why `a()` is much slower.

Beyond that, I endorse @Charles Duffy's comment:  worrying about micro-optimization is usually counterproductive in Python.  But, if you must ;-) , learn how to use `dis.dis` so you're not fooled by *gross* differences in generated code, as happened in this specific case.